# What fruits can a poor servant of Mara and his host expect?

Tags: right-view, right-livelihood, right-speech, right-effort, right-intention

Say one has gravely fallen into slavehood by consuming 'free' and, almost unaware, is driven to steal and pull the Gems and it's heritage, into this evil bound. Almost unaware and deluded, he even thinks he does a good by following a Robin Hood like lane, trying to gain surface by pulling Sublime into his sink.

What does good householder think: Which fruit, by acts grave wrong view (taking ungiven, cheating, hiding up, disregard...), following demand and 'my right' (given by Lord Mara, industy and his host), has he and those he encourage likewise, to expects, how ever 'naively good' he might justify his ways, even it directly warned? Liberation or long time even lower slave of Mara and his host?

Sure, answer honest and in line with the teacher, after having reflected wise, might change ones ways, and one might not only seek for excuse old but change the way toward out. Yet those answers might be rare and less voted up, naturally, bound like-a-like.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking. if you are suggesting that it is strange to have people demanding respect and acknowledgment of their enlightenment on-line, I have to admit I find it... odd. I don't think these people are devils, I think they have invested something different to me into their practice and thinking about buddhism, probably partly due to disbelief in karma

Comment: Why react on somethink when not understanding, out of range, then, at first place? Capability of understanding as well a liberality isn't something one bears inherently, good householder. Yet not knowing understanding, is always cause of ones unskilked acts, and suffering with it. Does good householder think that he is currently deep caught in Maras Slavehood and bound to his hosts camps or does Mara and his host give him the feeling of being free like nowhere else?

Comment: I have not studied much about 'mara'

Comment: So in that case easy possible that this question could be exactly about good householder, right here, or?

Comment: I don't know enough about anyone here to consider them frauds, but I don't wish to have your enlightenment forced down my throat on-line

Comment: Why not simply investigating seriously? Not-knowing isn't a protection at all, but root cause. There isn't any such as consumer-protection behind the bars, out there.